# How to ease high SoftIRQ (si) CPU

Tags: linux, kernel

Using LVS or Nginx for load balancing on CentOS under high network volume.
Network traffic is mainly small packets with a lot of connection and relatively low bandwidth.

The only thing that seems to become the bottleneck is high SoftIRQ which come as no surprise on event based IO.

Machine has 4 NICs but only one is enabled.

Linux kernel experts should know whether connecting more NICs would ease some of the software interrupts on Multiprocessor.

Comment: You should ask that on serverfault

Comment: Well, enable the other three as well! (As their interrupts can potentially be routed to other CPUs/cores.)

Answer (score 1):

I've dealing with a similar situation in the past, where a high rate of incoming packages are not properly handled by the network card driver. This driver was the default on Xen.

So basically the only option I had at that point (after upgrade which did not solve anything), was to try with a different card / driver, which made the problem to go away.